# No Content Assist in Eclipse QVT Operational editor

Tags: eclipse, emf, qvt

I'm writing a QVT model to model transformation from ecore to a DDS model.  I've Ecplise 3.7.2 and the last QVT Operational plugin 3.1.0v2.
The problem is that the content assist doesn't show me the properties of the meta-model entities.
For example I've no proposals for self.name in this dummy example:

```
modeltype OPENDDS uses 'http://www.opendds.org/modeling/schemas/OpenDDS/1.0';
modeltype ECORE uses 'http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore';

transformation Ecore2DDS(in inModel : ECORE, out outModel : OPENDDS) {
    main() {
        inModel.rootObjects()[EPackage]->map ePackage2Model();
    }     

    mapping EPackage::ePackage2Model() : DcpsLib{
        name := self.name; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in the transformation declaration.
main and mappings have not to be inside the transformation body!

Answer (score 0):

Transformation, modeltype definitions and main are the main concepts in qvt. Your transformation begins in main method, calling the first mapping. Your issue is because you tried to add main method and mapping declaration inside the transformation specification.